# Custom time format excel: don't display zeros if hours or minutes are zeroes

Tags: excel, time, format

There was an question placed before and it got the answer:
Thanks for that.

*"Right now I have formatted my cell with:
h "hours" m "minutes"
So if my cell has 7:00, it displays as 7 hours 0 minutes. Is there a way to remove the hours or the minutes if these are zero? Something like 7 hours, or 0:30 as 30 minutes"*

The answer was:

*If you have Excel 2007 or later versions (but apparently not Excel for Mac 2011) you can achieve this with a combination of regular formatting and conditional formatting.
Assuming data in A1 down use a regular custom format like this
[<0.0415][m]" minutes";h "hours" m "minutes"
That will give you the same as your previous formatting except that any value < 01:00 will display like
30 minutes
Now you can add a conditional formatting condition. With column A selected do this
Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format > type this formula in the box
=MINUTE(A1)=0
Click the "format" button and set the following number format
h" hours"
Now if you have 16:00 in A1 that will display as just 16 hours
[conditional formatting rules will always supersede regular formatting]*

But I wonder if it is possible in addition to this add time format in a way like if I have 1 hour it shows "1 hour" (in singular) instead of "1 hours"?

Comment: Is it ok to delimite the column and show hours and minutes in 2 columns?

Comment: not really it should be within 1 cell

Comment: any luck on the tryout ?

Answer (score 8):

This should do this trick

Add this to Custom type box

```
[<0.0415][m] "minutes";[<0.083][h] "hour" m "minutes";[h] "hours" m "minutes"
```

inputs/outputs

```
inputs -
00:05:00
00:30:00
01:05:00
01:30:00
02:30:00

outputs -
5 minutes
30 minutes
1 hour 5 minutes
1 hour 30 minutes
2 hours 30 minutes
```

Notes

By putting the square bracket around [h] it will allow for more than 24 hours to be added e.g. 31 hours 30 minutes.

In Excel 1 minute is equal to 0.00069444 (1/1440 of a day). Knowing this helps to calculate the two less-then numbers.

Alternative option

If you just want h rather than hour and m rather than minutes try this

```
[<0.0415][mm] "m";[h] "h" mm "m"
```

Comment: Elegant, I like it.

Comment: Can also use [<0.0415][mm]:ss;[h]:mm:ss to show as just a numeric time format but only show the number of hours if it is greater than 0

Comment: Format code spec is here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68

Comment: For non-English speaking countries: change `.` to `,` (comma), e.g. [<0,0415]. Also, check if the variables `mm` (minute) and `h` (hour) also are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(HOUR(B9)<>0,HOUR(B9)&" hour"&IF(HOUR(B9)<>1,"s "," "),"")&IF(MINUTE(B9)<>0,MINUTE(B9)&" minute"&IF(MINUTE(B9)<>1,"s",""),"")
```

TLDR : extract every values manually > then put if conditions for 0,1 and other > print value..

Hope it helps.